# Mutate an array through a slice of the array

Tags: rust

```
let mut a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let mut window = &a[1..4];
for element in window.iter() {
    println!("{}", element);
    *element = 0;
}
```

How to set the middle values in the original array `a` to `0` through the slice `window`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your precise case, if you don't try to make overlapping slices, you can simply create a `&mut` slice:

```
let mut a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let window = &mut a[1..4];
for element in window.iter_mut() {
    println!("{}", element);
    *element = 0;
}
```

Comment: Note also that the `.iter_mut()` is superfluous.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan It depends: if you allow `window` to be consumed by the loop, then yes it is superfluous.

Comment: Tried this method to mutate a `[[i32; 128]; 512]`, with no success yet